# How to hide/show list items with javascript onclick menu.

Tags: javascript, onclick, html-lists, toggle, mapbox

I am using Mapbox and have a menu that toggles the markers on and off as well as a list generated by javascript and populated with the marker titles. What I need is for the list items to change when the different categories are toggled, rather than showing the whole list. Is it possible to do this with an if, else statement? 

Here is a link to the live map: [Visual Map for Visual Art](http://de-fine-art.com/fullscreenmap)
 and here is the script (I left out some redundant menu onclick codes which I haven't figured out how to combine so that I don't have to repeat for every menu item):

```html
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGUtZmluZS1hcnQiLCJhIjoidFJyclFabyJ9.sBXgFmwT-4dhGAevwEmKuA';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'de-fine-art.lh9dpd0k'),
        markerList = document.getElementById('marker-list');
        sxsw = document.getElementById('filter-sxsw'),
        performance = document.getElementById('filter-performance'),
        miscellaneous = document.getElementById('filter-miscellaneous'),
        party = document.getElementById('filter-party'),
        streetart = document.getElementById('filter-streetart'),
        gallery = document.getElementById('filter-gallery'),
        museum = document.getElementById('filter-museum'),
        all = document.getElementById('filter-all');
        
      

  map.featureLayer.on('ready', function(e) {
      map.featureLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
          var item = markerList.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
          item.innerHTML = layer.toGeoJSON().properties.title;
          item.style.background = layer.toGeoJSON().properties['marker-color'];
          item.onclick = function() {
             map.setView(layer.getLatLng(), 16);
             layer.openPopup();
          };
      });
  });
      museum.onclick = function(e) {
        all.className = '';
        gallery.className = '';
        streetart.className = '';
        party.className = '';
        miscellaneous.className = '';
        performance.className = '';
        sxsw.className = '';
        this.className = 'active';
        // The setFilter function takes a GeoJSON feature object
        // and returns true to show it or false to hide it.
        map.featureLayer.setFilter(function(f) {
            return f.properties['marker-symbol'] === 'museum';
        });
        return false;
    };

    all.onclick = function() {
        museum.className = '';
        gallery.className = '';
        streetart.className = '';
        party.className = '';
        miscellaneous.className = '';
        performance.className = '';
        sxsw.className = '';
        this.className = 'active';
        map.featureLayer.setFilter(function(f) {
            // Returning true for all markers shows everything.
            return true;
        });
        return false;
    };
    


</script>`
```

Comment: why are you making `className` empty?..for simple hide/show, you should check for `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`, depending on the requirement

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar that looks that way so that when a category is active it makes all other ones inactive, otherwise they will stay blue.